# iPhone SDK Managing Memory for Multiview app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uilabel, multiview

I have an app that programmatically creates labels and text fields based on the contents of a text file. Whenever the view controller is loaded, it creates text fields and labels that are different each time. My problem is I need to clear out the labels and text fields without releasing the view controller since I need to keep track of the view controller. I tried `self.viewController = nil`, but I'm pretty sure this results in a memory leak. Is there a way to delete all the subviews of a view?

Answer (score 3):

What Greg meant to say is this:

```
for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

This may not work as you would expect though, as Objective C doesn't like it when you modify an array while you're iterating through it in a for loop.  A safer choice would be this:

```
while ([self.view.subviews count] > 0) { 
    [[self.view.subviews lastObject] removeFromSuperview]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a view named `view`, you should be able to remove all of the subviews from the view using this code:

```
for (UIView *subview in view) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```